# Should I use "other" or "another" in the following case?

Tags: grammar

> The dogs were put in pairs, one with a lever that stopped the shocks,
>   and **other/another** with a lever that didn't.

Should I use **other** or **another**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use both `other` and `another`.

`other` is used in a sentence before the plural or uncountable nouns.

```
     `eg: other people have problems too.`
```

but `another` is used in a sentence before the singular and countable nouns.

```
    `eg:  I would like another piece of cake`
```

here in this sentence use of `another` will be correct, because you are representing a single dog not group of dogs.

Comment: you meant *another*?

Comment: @alexchenco yes I did a mistake. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Your first example should read "other people have problems too"

Comment: @Mark I have edited.

Answer (score 3):

Because you've already introduced the dogs earlier on in the sentence I'd go with:

> The dogs were put in pairs, one with a lever that stopped the shocks, and the other with a lever that didn't.

Notice I can't say "... and other with...", I need to add the definite article.

Comment: Correct. Here the use of **the** is mandatory. **a/an** + **other** = **another**. Here **another** is also possible to use but **the other** is better.

Answer (score 1):

First, the phrase should be:

> The dogs were put in pairs, one with a lever that stopped the shocks, and **the other (another)** with a lever that didn't.

When you use *the other*, it is choosing the second of two options or items. In the phrase above, you are indicating there are only two pair of dogs.

When you use *another*, it is choosing a different option or item amongst an unknown quantity. In the phrase above, you can't tell how many pairs of dogs there are.

You should choose which one fits your situation.